# How to app.config value from server location in c#

Tags: c#, configuration

I wanna read/write (and use) application's configuration file in program

**app.config of server**

```
  <configSections>
   <section />
  </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
  <add name="catalogue" connectionString="Data Source=abc\_SQLSERVER;Initial 
  Catalog=Catalogue;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=False; user ID=sa;password=****;" 
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
      </connectionStrings>
        <dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="Catalogue"/>
     <startup>

  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>
 <appSettings>


     </appSettings>
    </configuration>
```

I want to use the app.config file which is present at the following location on some other server location '\abc\BaseSoftwares\hanah\abc.exe.config' instead of local configuration.
Using **ConfigurationManager. OpenExeConfiguration**

```
    string pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(CentralizedPath, "abc.exe.config"); 
    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(pathString);

    ConnectionStringsSection section = config.GetSection("connectionStrings") as 
         ConnectionStringsSection;
```

section is not returning the connection string of server app config which is [catalogue].
    Anyone who could help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

1. ConnectionStringsSection().ConnectionStrings gives the collection of all connection strings in your config.
2. Iterate through to get the required result.

```
ConnectionStringSettingsCollection collection= config.ConnectionStringsSection().ConnectionStrings;

foreach(ConnectionStringSettings css in collection)
{
   string output= css.Name;
}
```